# RegisterWaitForSingleObject To Watch a Directory using RealBasic

Tags: windows, callback, realbasic

I'm trying to watch a directory for changes using the [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This works if I take the handle returned by FindFirstChangeNotification and stuff it into WaitForSingleObject. The problem is that WaitForSingleObject blocks the entire application until it returns.

So, I looked around and it seems that [RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was the way to go:

```
Sub monitorDir(dir As FolderItem)
  Declare Function FindFirstChangeNotificationW Lib "Kernel32" (dirPath As WString, watchChildren As Boolean, eventTypeFilter As Integer) As Integer
  Declare Function RegisterWaitForSingleObject Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef waiterHWND As Integer, HWND As Integer, cllbck As Ptr, _
  context As Integer, wait As Integer, flags As Integer) As Integer
  Dim allFilters As Integer = &h00000001 Or &h00000002 Or &h00000004 Or &h00000008 Or &h00000010_
      Or &h00000100
  Dim monitorHandle As Integer = FindFirstChangeNotificationW(dir.AbsolutePath, True, allFilters)
  If monitorHandle <> 0 Then
  Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject(myCallbackHWND, monitorHandle, AddressOf MyCallbackFn, 0, &hFFFFFFFF, 0)
End Sub
```

This *appears* to work as the application continues to execute normally. However, as soon as the MyCallbackFn is called (that is, when a change occurs in the directory) things get... weird. Applications start crashing or locking up starting with Process Explorer and Windows Explorer. I have to log out of Windows in order to restore things.

At the moment, all that MyCallbackFn does is this:

```
Sub MyCallbackFn()
  Declare Function UnregisterWaitEx Lib "Kernel32" (waitHWND As Integer, eventHandle As Integer) As Integer
  Call UnregisterWaitEx(myCallbackHWND, 0)
  MsgBox("Change Detected")
End Sub
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree by using RegisterWaitForSingleObject, have I used it wrongly, or there some limitation in RealBasic which causes callbacks to implode the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function you register in `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` is called on another thread (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685061.aspx):

> The callback routine is executed by a worker thread when the object's state becomes signaled or the time-out interval elapses.

I don't know anything about RealBasic's threading support, but at the very least GUI operations on Windows typically need to occur on a specific thread, not just any old worker thread. So the call to `MsgBox()` on that worker thread is probably a problem.

A simple thing you can try is to call `PostMessage()` (or whatever the RealBasic equivalent is) to post a custom message to your window message queue that your application can respond to (for example by calling `MsgBox()`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed the MsgBox call but it had no effect and things still started crashing. Removing the call to UnregisterWaitEx stopped the crashes but causes the Callback function to be called over and over for a single change.

Comment: @Amazed: these suggestions might not be good, since I don't really know RealBasic: by any chance is your RealBasic app built for 64-bit?  If so, I think that the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` declaration might not be right (if RealBasic  `Integer` is a 32-bit object like C/C++ `int` is on Win64). Also, does RealBasic generate calling conventions that are compatible with Win32 callbacks by default? You may need to mark the `MyCallbackFn()` with some RealBasic keyword/attribute/declaration so the compiler will know that the function is being called from Windows, not from other RealBasic code.

Comment: RealBasic cannot compile 64 bit executables at this time, it's strictly 32 bit. As for the calling convention, I'll have to give that a whirl later. Realbasic has a pragma directive for defining a method's calling convention, but I've never had cause to use it (of course I've never written a callback function before either.) The directive takes a parameter of wither "StdCall" or CDecl" which I interpret as "Standard Call" and "C Declare." Which would you suggest? I seem to recall reading that Win32 uses StdCall?

Comment: A Win32 callback would use the StdCall convention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related, but where is MyCallBackFn() declared?  If it is an instance method you should use WeakAddressOf instead of AddressOf.

Comment: MyCallbackFn is declared in a Module. Using WeakAddressOf crashed the IDE :(